# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Tags: apex, failing-tests, future, dmlexception

I'm getting the below error while running the test class. Can anyone help on this please?

Error :

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a057h000002BqVUAA0; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

[image]

Class:

```java
public class CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow {
       
    @InvocableMethod(label='Exception Log From Flow')
    public static void exceptionLogFromFlow(List<Params> inputVars) {
        set<Id> logId = new set<Id>();
        createExceptionLog(logId);
    }
    
    @future
    public static void createExceptionLog(set<Id> logId){
        String apexClass;
        String methodName;
        String exceptionMessage;
        DateTime exceptionDated;
        String userName;
        
        for(Id sfID : logId){                         
            ExceptionLogger__c log = new ExceptionLogger__c();
            log.Id = sfID;
            log.Apex_Class__c = apexClass;
            log.Method_Name__c = methodName;
            log.Description__c = exceptionMessage;
            log.Exception_Dated__c = exceptionDated;
            log.User_Name__c = userName;
            insert log;
        }           
    }        
    public class Params {
        @InvocableVariable public String apexClass;
        @InvocableVariable public String methodName;
        @InvocableVariable public String exceptionMessage;
        @InvocableVariable public DateTime exceptionDated;
        @InvocableVariable public Boolean isAPIFailure;
        @InvocableVariable public String userName;
    }
    
}
```

Test Class :

```java
@IsTest
public with sharing class CS_ExceptionLoggerFlowTest {
    
    @IsTest
    public static void testExceptionLog() {
        
        ExceptionLogger__c log = new ExceptionLogger__c(Apex_Class__c = 'CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow',
                                                        Method_Name__c = 'exceptionLogFromFlow',
                                                        Description__c = 'message',
                                                        Exception_Dated__c = System.today(),
                                                        User_Name__c = 'userName'
                                                       );                                     
        insert log;
                
        Set<Id> logIds = new Set<Id>();
        logIds.add(log.id);
        Test.startTest();
        CS_ExceptionLoggerFlow.createExceptionLog(logIds);
        Test.stopTest();
        List<ExceptionLogger__c> logs = [SELECT Id FROM ExceptionLogger__c];
        System.AssertEquals(1, logs.size(), 'Should insert one ExceptionLogger__c record');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please always include code/errors as _text_ rather than images.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! To elaborate on *Adrian Larson*'s comment, Please do not post error text exclusively as a screenshot - it is not as accessible to users who use screen readers or other assistive technology. The convention here on SFSE is to format error text with a greater than symbol (>) at the beginning to format it as a quote block - it helps it to stand out.

Comment: I have updated the post with error message. Sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your `@future` method has a syntax error in it.

```
for(Id sfID : logId){                         
    ExceptionLogger__c log = new ExceptionLogger__c();
    log.Id = sfID;
    log.Apex_Class__c = apexClass;
    log.Method_Name__c = methodName;
    log.Description__c = exceptionMessage;
    log.Exception_Dated__c = exceptionDated;
    log.User_Name__c = userName;
    insert log; // This is the problematic line
}
```

As the error is telling you, you cannot insert a record if it already has an Id. You are specifically setting the Id with `log.Id = sfID;`.

You need to perform an `update` here instead.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify Id value for any record which you are inserting, it will be unique value for a record. Either insert the record without Id value (i.e. log.Id = sfID;) or if those log records are present thn create new field on the object and assign sfID value to that new field in update operation.